# Extension of the SEARCH command: X-GM-RAW with PHP & the Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, gmail, gmail-imap

I am trying to use the Zend Framework with PHP to extend the SEARCH function with X-GM-RAW but cannot get it to work. This my code.

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php';
require_once "Zend/Mail/Protocol/Imap.php";
require_once "Zend/Registry.php";
$protocol = new Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap('imap.gmail.com', 993, true);
$protocol->login($user, $pass);
$protocol->select('INBOX');
$protocol->requestAndResponse('X-GM-RAW', 'category:primary');
$storage = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($protocol);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly which error is happening to you (you should give some explanation of what are you trying to do and the error you have) but I would change the:

```
$protocol->requestAndResponse('X-GM-RAW', 'category:primary');
```

to

```
$rawMessages = $protocol->search(array('X-GM-RAW "category:primary"'));
```

Hope it will be useful.